# how to add values in "__init__" to the list of VALUES with the meta class

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

How do I add self.value 1 and self.value 2 into VALUES . this is the purpose
How can I add "self.value1" and "self.value2" to the VALUES list inside the meta class

```
class Meta(type):
    VALUES = dict()

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        for k, v in attrs.items():
            print(k, v)
        return super(Meta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)


class A(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value1 = "Class A"


class B(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value2 = "Class B"


class Main(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()


m = Main()
print(m.__dict__)
```

the output i wanted
{'value1': 'Class A',"value2":"Class B"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you call the super() function, it doesn't call all instances of the function, only the first one it finds. Because your class definition inherits A before it inherits B, the first class to be searched is class A. The program finds the **init** function inside class A so it executed that and then returns. If you were instead to write `class Main(B, A):`, the output would be `{"value2":"Class B"}`, because then class B is higher in the search order than A.

To solve the problem you have, you would have to run all of the inherited class's **init** functions, for example like this:

```
class Main(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        for cls in Main.__bases__:
            cls.__init__(self)
```

This takes a reference from each parent class from the **bases** attribute and calls their **init** directly, meaning that it is called from every parent class, not just the highest priority one. I'm not sure if this is best practice or even sensible at all but it should the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

`super` is meant to be used *cooperatively*, by *all* classes in the hierarchy. (Ignoring the metaclass, since it is irrelevant to the requested result.)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self. **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.value1 = "Class A"


class B:
    def __init__(self. **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.value2 = "Class B"


class Main(A, B):
    pass

m = Main()
```

Since `Main.__init__` isn't defined, the first `__init__` method found in the MRO is called first, namely `A.__init__`. `A.__init__` then uses `super()` to call `B.__init__`, which uses `super()` to call `object.__init__`, which is the last method in the chain, as `object.__init__` itself does not use `super`.

Note that both `A` and `B` use `super` without knowing which class's `__init__` method will be used next. That is determined by the type of the object passed as `self`, not the class.